# Overload for undefined type

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to do some overload on the template function, following are the examples

do_something.h

```
template<typename T>
void do_something(T const &input){/*....*/}

void do_something(std::string const &input);

void do_something(boost::container::string const &input);
```

so far, so good, but what if I want to overload a non-defined type?

like using a type `some_type` have not defined in the header file

```
void do_something(some_type const &input);
```

I want to use it like this

main.cpp

```
#include "do_something.h"
#include "some_type.h"

#include <boost/container/string.hpp>

int main()
{
     do_something(std::string("whatever"));
     do_something(boost::container::string("whatever"));

     //oops, some_type() never defined in the header file, this
     //function will call the template version, but this is not
     //the behavior user expected
     do_something(some_type());   
}
```

Since some_type is not a POD, not a std::string, boost::container::string.I guess I could designed a traits to do some compile time checking

```
template<typename T>
typename boost::enable_if<is_some_type<T>::value, T>::type
do_something(T const &input){//.....}
```

But do I have a better way to do it?

I need compile time type checking, so I use template.All of the types calling this function will do similar jobs based on different types, so I prefer overload.I do not need to save the state, so I prefer function rather than class.
Hope this could help you know more about what I intent to do.Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure,could you use static_assert in template?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> but what if I want to overload a non-defined type?

You need to provide the declaration of

```
void do_something(some_type const &input);
```

before you call `do_something` with an object of type `some_type`. Otherwise, the template version will be used.

```
#include "do_something.h"
#include "some_type.h"

// This is all you need. You can implement the function here
// or any other place of your choice.
void do_something(some_type const &input);

#include <boost/container/string.hpp>

int main()
{
     do_something(std::string("whatever"));
     do_something(boost::container::string("whatever"));

     //oops, some_type() never defined in the header file, this
     //function will call the template version, but this is not
     //the behavior user expected
     do_something(some_type());   
}
```